# eclipse maven - Run on server - ClassNotFound

Tags: eclipse, maven

I maven-build my application (has a single servlet) with '`clean install`' and it creates war in target folder. If I copy it to webapps in tomcat and it works fine. But if I do Run on server it fails with ClassNotFoundException on the servlet.

Deployment assembly includes maven dependencies.

Comment: it fails for which class ? that class is certainly not present in your deployment artifact

Comment: Can you please share a complete stacktrace?

Comment: Run on server creates the folders of 'myapp; as below and also copies jars but not class files.  workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/web. Here classes of this package are not copied hence getting ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.myapp.web.MyAppStartupListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.web.MyAppStartupListener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)

Comment: Within the same folder I have a Servlet which is also not available in that folder while Run On Server